# Test functionality with timeouts in react-testing-library and jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to follow TDD, and I have a `span` that should appear on screen after 5 seconds. I haven't implemented the span at all, so the test should fail, but currently it passes the test `expect(messageSpan).toBeInTheDocument`.

Here are my two tests:

```
it("doesn't show cta message at first", () => {
    render(<FAB />);
    const messageSpan = screen.queryByText(
      "Considering a career in nursing? Join our team!"
    );
    expect(messageSpan).toBeNull(); // passes, as it should
  });

  it("should show the cta message after 5 secs", () => {
    render(<FAB />);
    setTimeout(() => {
      const messageSpan = screen.getByText( // also tried queryByText instead of get
        "Considering a career in nursing? Join our team!"
      );
      expect(messageSpan).toBeInTheDocument(); // also passes, even though messageSpan should throw an error.
    }, 5000);
  });
```

Here's my `FAB` component, where you can see there's no message at all:

```
export default function FAB() {
  return (
// using styled-components; there's no content in any of these.
    <StyledFABContainer>
      <StyledFABButton>
        <BriefcaseIcon />
      </StyledFABButton>
    </StyledFABContainer>
  );
}
```

To complicate things, I don't plan to have a set function I call for the `setTimeout`. I will simply set state after a set time of 5 secs. So don't think I can use the suggestions in the timer mocks section of jest docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks

My two questions are:

a) Why would this pass and not throw an error/null?
b) How can I properly test `setTimeout` functionality in RTL?

UPDATE: Have tried using various combinations of `useFakeTimers`, `act`, `waitFor` etc., but no luck. Here's my current test as it's written out, and throwing two errors - one saying I need to use `act` when changing state (which I am, but still) and one saying my `messageSpan` is null:

```js
it("cta message to display after 5 secs", async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const el = document.createElement("div");
    act(() => {
      ReactDOM.render(<FAB />, el);
    });
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);
    const messageSpan = screen.queryByText(
      "Considering a career in nursing? Join our team!"
    );
    expect(messageSpan).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

If working with an asynchronous test I found a solution on this blog: https://onestepcode.com/testing-library-user-event-with-fake-timers/

The trick is to set the `delay` option on the `userEvent` to `null`.

```
const user = userEvent.setup({ delay: null });
```

Here is a full test case

```
test("Pressing the button hides the text (fake timers)", async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup({ delay: null });
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    
    render(<Demo />);

    const button = screen.getByRole("button");
    await user.click(button);

    act(() => {
        jest.runAllTimers();
    });

    const text = screen.queryByText("Hello World!");
    expect(text).not.toBeInTheDocument();

    jest.useRealTimers();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use setTimeout like this in your tests. An obvious reason would be that you do not want to wait 5 seconds in your test to then continue. Imagine a component that would change after 10min. You cant wait that long but should use jests [mocked timers API](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks) instead.
You can progress the nodejs timer so your component changes, then immediately make your assertion.
Other remarks about the tests you wrote:

- If you are awaiting changes you should use await waitFor(() => ...) from testing library. It checks the expectations to pass every 50ms by default for a total of 5sec. If all expectations pass it continues. You should make asynchronous assertions there.
- "expect(messageSpan).toBeNull()" should be "expect(messageSpan).not.toBeInTheDocument()". Its good to go with the accessibility way testing library provides.

Comment: I tried out with `waitFor` and didn't get much luck. I also tried using `act` because my terminal was complaining about my updating state in my `useEffect` without using `act`. I also have tried using a fake timer and advancing time by 5000ms. None of them work, unfortunately. Updated my question with this new code.